# Can't convert TensorFlow saved model to tfjs_layers_model webmodel

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to convert TensorFlow saved model to tfjs webmodel, but it gives a `ValueError`.

The code I used can be found [here](https://github.com/PatrickLib/captcha_recognize).

I have pretrained models in `mobilenet/saved_model`, `.ckpt`, `.meta`, `.index`, and checkpoint files.

```
tensorflowjs_converter     --input_format=tf_saved_model  --output_format=tfjs_layers_model   --signature_name=serving_default     --saved_model_tags=serve mobilenet/saved_model/ mobilenet/web_model/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shiva/.local/bin/tensorflowjs_converter", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/shiva/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflowjs/converters/converter.py", line 373, in main
    (input_format, output_format))
ValueError: Unsupported input_format - output_format pair: tf_saved_model - tfjs_layers_model
```

Comment: I think it is not support according to [**Format Conversion Support Tables**](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter) It supports conversion from _tf_saved_model_ to _tfjs_graph_model_